# Google Spreadsheets function to get a cell from a range by row and col name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a range

```
      idz01  idz04  ida02
foo     a      1      b
bar     c      3      8
baz     8      2      g
```

And I want to get values from this range, like this:

```
SOME_FUNCTION(rangeID, 'foo', 'idz04')
```

to get `1`, etc. Or ideally, to get the cell:

```
INDIRECT(SOME_FUNCTION(rangeID, 'foo', 'idz04'))
```

or such.

Is there something such? Can the `GETPIVOTDATA()` be used for that?

*Edit:*
I could somehow employ the `LOOKUP` if I was able to get the `result_range`:

```
LOOKUP("foo", DataRange, 
    FIRST_COL(
        OFFSET(DataRange, 
            MATCH("idz04", FIRST_ROW(DataRange), 0)
        )
    )
)
```

Only, I don't have `FIRST_ROW()` and `FIRST_COL()`... Maybe `FILTER()` could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it goes:

```
=INDEX(ObjednavkyData, 
   // Find the offset of "vesela01" in the 1st column
   MATCH("vesela01",
     OFFSET((ObjednavkyData),0,0,
        MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(ObjednavkyData)))  // Num of rows in the range
     , 1)
   ,0), 
   // Find the offset of "z03" in the 1st row
   MATCH("z03", 
     OFFSET(ObjednavkyData, 0 , 0, 1)  // First row
   , 0))
```

Not really neat :P
Also see [Google Spreadsheets: How to get a first (Nth) row/column from a range? (built-in functions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857651/google-spreadsheets-how-to-get-a-first-nth-row-column-from-a-range-built-in/30857708#30857708)

Answer (score 4):

Try this, you just need to set ranges:

```
=INDEX("Talbe",MATCH("foo","First Column",0),MATCH("idz04","First Row",0))
```

For example if your table is in the range A1:D4, use:

```
=INDEX(A1:D4,MATCH("foo",A:A,0),MATCH("idz04",1:1,0))
```

You can also use named ranges

---

To get first columns and rows automatically use this formula:

```
=INDEX(data,MATCH("foo",INDIRECT(CHAR(64+COLUMN(data))&":"&CHAR(64+COLUMN(data))),0),MATCH("idz04",INDIRECT(COLUMN(data)&":"&COLUMN(data)),0))
```

---

To do this via script, use this code:

```
function LOOKUPGRID(data, rowHeader, colHeader) {
  for (var i = 0; i<data.length;i++) {
    if (data[i][0] === rowHeader) {
      for (var j = 0; j<data[0].length;j++) {
        if (data[0][j] === colHeader) {
          return (data[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return (null)
}
```

You can then call the formula in your sheet like this:

```
=LOOKUPGRID(A1:D4,"foo","idz04")
```

Comment: That's quite nice. Could I also automate getting the first column and first row? So that I don't have to substract the range's offset: `MATCH("z04",1:1,0)-1)`

Comment: Got it, see the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

For this you could write a custom function using Google Apps Script. Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) for more details.

You could access the spread sheet with name or id and get the range of values(in your case a cell).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Tried to write my own function...

```
/**
 * Returns [Range] the cell value at coordinates determined by the values first row (colHeader) and first column (rowHeader) in given range.
 */ 
function LOOKUP_GRID(range, colHeader, rowHeader){
  for(var col = range.getWidth()-1; col--; col  >= 0 )
    if(range.getCell(1, col).getValue() === colHeader)
      break;
  for(var row = range.getHeight()-1; row--; row  >= 0 )
    if(range.getCell(row, 1).getValue() === rowHeader)
      break;

  if(col === -1 || row === -1)
    return null;
  else
    return range.getCell(row, column)
}
```