# Google Spreadsheets: How to get a first (Nth) row/column from a range? (built-in functions)

Tags: google-sheets

Say I have this named range, not at A1.

```
      idz01  idz04  ida02
foo     a      1      b
bar     c      3      8
baz     8      2      g
```

Now how can I get the first row? And Nth row? And how the Nth column? As a range, using the built-in functions.

Edit: Nth row: `=OFFSET(ObjednavkyData, N,0, 1)`
Last row:

```
=OFFSET(ObjednavkyData, 
    MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(ObjednavkyData)))-ROW(ObjednavkyData), 0, 1
 )
```

Comment: Are you trying to get first column and first row as a range to use it with formula I gave in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809066/google-spreadsheets-function-to-get-a-cell-from-a-range-by-row-and-col-name) ?

Answer (score 35):

Just use the `INDEX` function:

```
=INDEX(NamedRange1,NRow,NColumn)
```

If you want the last row and column you can use:

```
=INDEX(NamedRange1,ROWS(NamedRange1),COLUMNS(NamedRange1))
```

- `INDEX` is more efficient than the alternative `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` that are volatile.

Examples:

```
=INDEX(ObjednavkyData,3,2) //This will return "c".
=INDEX(ObjednavkyData,ROWS(ObjednavkyData),COLUMNS(ObjednavkyData2)) //This will return "g".
```

**Addition:**

If you want to get the whole row, you can omit the `column` part of the `INDEX` function. And if you need the whole column, omit the `row` part (by putting `0` in the `row` field).

```
=INDEX(ObjednavkyData,3)    //This will return row 3:    "bar       c      3      8".
=INDEX(ObjednavkyData,0, 2) //This will return column 2: "idz01     a      c      8".
```

Comment: I believe he is trying to pull the whole column/row, not just a cell. He wants to use them with index as posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809066/google-spreadsheets-function-to-get-a-cell-from-a-range-by-row-and-col-name)

Comment: Right, I need the whole row or column. I could possibly solve the task in the other question using `INDEX()` and `MATCH()`, too. But for that I would still need to get the first row somehow, to search it with LOOKUP.

Comment: If you omit the [column] part of the INDEX function you will get the whole row. I will add this to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

There are now dedicated functions called [`CHOOSEROWS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13196659) and [`CHOOSECOLS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914) for this. They work with any array, such as the output of another function, and can select multiple rows or columns.

To select the first row:

```
=CHOOSEROWS(ObjednavkyData, 1)
```

To select the last row:

```
=CHOOSEROWS(ObjednavkyData, -1)
```

To select the Nth row:

```
=CHOOSEROWS(ObjednavkyData, N)
```

To select the first three rows:

```
=CHOOSEROWS(ObjednavkyData, 1, 2, 3)
```

Substitute `CHOOSECOLS` for `CHOOSEROWS` to select columns instead.

Comment: Better way to select the **first N** rows: `=CHOOSEROWS(ObjednavkyData, SEQUENCE(N))`

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer: (still open to better ones)

1st row

```
OFFSET(Data, 0 , 0, 1)
```

First column:

You simply can call some functions on the range and they take 1st column.
  Or, if needed:

```
OFFSET(Data, 0, 0, MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(Data))), 1)
```

Nth row:
The key here is that `OFFSET()` only fills right and down. So you only need to crop these directions by it's parameters.

```
OFFSET(Data, N, 0, 1);
```

Could be also achieved by feeding the first row to `ARRAYFORMULA()` and for each column (cell), get the last row's cell using `INDEX(COLUMN(),ROW() + N)`.

Nth column:

Similarly to above, only you need to get the number of rows.

```
OFFSET(Data, 0, N, ROWS(Data), 1);
```

I was playing with `TRANSPOSE()` but seems that `OFFSET()` doesn't digest it well.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to propose an alternative method, that works also with volatile unnamed ranges (e.g. output from other functions, not just ranges that exist on the spreadsheet.)  The general idea is to use FILTER() as the mechanism of extractions, and construct a vector of true/false values as an indicator of which rows to extract. So for instance, if the source range is A1:D13 and I want to extract row 7, I would write

```
=filter(
   A1:D13,
   {transpose(split(rept("0 ", 6), " "));
    1;
    transpose(split(rept("0 ", rows(A1:D13)-7), " "))
   }
  )
```

As you can see, it's also easy to generalize to extracting any number of rows from anywhere. In general terms construct the formula like that:

```
=filter(
   <data>,
   {transpose(split(rept("0 ", <number rows to skip from the start>), " "));
    transpose(split(rept("1 ", <number of rows to extract>), " "));
    transpose(split(rept("0 ", <number of rows to skip until the end), " "))
   }
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

First Row:

```
=INDIRECT(COLUMN(data)&":"&COLUMN(data))
```

First Column:

```
=INDIRECT(CHAR(64+COLUMN(data))&":"&CHAR(64+COLUMN(data)))
```

N'th row:

```
=INDIRECT(COLUMN(data)+N&":"&COLUMN(data)+N)
```

N'th Column:

```
=INDIRECT(CHAR(64+COLUMN(data)+N)&":"&CHAR(64+COLUMN(data)+N))
```

Substitute data with your data range and N with the row/column that you need in the data. Row's/Column's are counted starting with 0. You can change that buy using **N-1** instead.

If you want to get the actual range (A:A,1:1,A3:A3) instead of the values, just ged rid of the **INDIRECT** in these formulas

Hope this helps