# How to get a first (Nth) row/column from a FILTERED range? (built-in functions)

Tags: google-sheets

I tried to use the OFFSET answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857651/google-spreadsheets-how-to-get-a-first-nth-row-column-from-a-range-built-in#) but it did not work with my range returned by a FILTER function. The error message was "Argument must be a range.".

Is it because FILTER does not return a range or am I making another mistake?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`INDEX()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) function.

Syntax: `INDEX(reference, [row], [column])`

Get 2nd row: `INDEX(YourRange, 2)`

Get 3rd column: `INDEX(YourRange, , 3)` or `INDEX(YourRange, 0, 3)`